# How to disable autohotkey in visual studio?

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I would like to have an AHK script be disabled when I have the Microsoft Visual Studio window activated (basically, when I'm in it). How could I do that?

```
#IfWinNotActive Model (Debugging) - Microsoft Visual Studio (Administrator)
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
SetNumLockState, AlwaysOn
SetScrollLockState, AlwaysOff
F1::Send !{F4}
F2::^+Tab
F3::^Tab
F4::^t
F6::^w
F7::!Esc
F8::#Down
CapsLock::Enter
^Esc::#d
F9::#1
F10::#2
F11::#3
F12::#4

return
```

Thanks

Comment: Also check [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Context) and [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I checked them out and have updated the question with what I have now in the script (it still doesn't work, I assume because the ahk_class for MS Visual Studio is not a fixed name, but something in the form of: 'ahk_class HwndWrapper[DefaultDomain;;7018e796-0eb5-41c9-8893-cbf68445dc49]', with the final string varying for every instance of VS. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: try using [wingetclass](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetClass.htm) to find it

Comment: wingetclass displays the same ahk_class than AHK window spy, it does not work -functionality remains the same in or outside VS. I updated the code above.

Comment: did you try `#ifwinactive, Microsoft Visual Studio` or variants based on your edition?

Comment: Just made it work, thanks a lot! I succeeded with the whole window title. Is there any way to have several #ifwinnotactive at the same time? (not only the one mentioned, but others as well)

Comment: I wouldn't see why not, it should be based on the active window

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use the [#ifwinactive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfWinActive.htm) protocol to set up "profiles" dependent on which window you are in.